# Is inside range

Tags: range, contains, nim-lang

Say you have the following type:

```
type Min = 1..4
```

You want to check whether some int falls inside Min as you can with sets:

```
's' in {'a'..'z'}
```

It is possible to express it more elengantly than:

```
2 in {low(Min)..high(Min)}  #Too many characters
2 in Min                    #Expecting this conciseness
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you break up the restriction of `1..4` being a type, it's easily possible. `1..4` as a value makes it a `Slice` instead of a `range`. I don't know what else you do with `Min`, but as a slice it supports the `in` syntax via a `contains` proc:

```
echo 2 in 1..4

let Min = 1..4
echo 2 in Min
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene, added an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The issue that you are dealing with is that `Min` is a type and the right-hand side of the `in` operator expects an expression. You can handle this either by overloading the `in` operator as a template that accepts a type argument or by providing a template to convert a type to the underlying range expression.

Overloading `in`:

```
type Min = 1..4

template `in`[T](x: T, tp: typedesc[range]): bool =
  x in (tp.low .. tp.high)

echo 2 in Min
```

Converting a type to a range:

```
type Min = 1..4

template rg(tp: typedesc[range]): expr =
  tp.low .. tp.high

echo 2 in rg Min
```

Comment: You answer actually fits the question, but i feel that def-'s answer is what i was looking for (it's easy to misuse types) and most will find it more useful. Still i learnt a lot from your answer, thanks Reimer.